# CButtonColumn for another model in CGridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii, cbuttoncolumn

I'm showing a CGridView for another related model in `view&id=n` page. The necessary relations are included in model files and everything works just fine. The only thing is that the buttons in the `CButtonColumn` are linked to the appropriate actions of the model which page is being opened, while I want them to link to the actions of the related model.

To explain clear what I mean, here is my code. In `view.php` of `Order` model:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('OrderContents', array(
'criteria'=>array(
    'condition'=>'order_id='.$model->id,
    'with'=>array('order'),
),
'pagination'=>array(
    'pageSize'=>20,
),
));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'orders-contents-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
            'id',
            'comp_name',
            'quantity',
            'comment',
            array(
                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            ),
    ),
));
```

Thus, I want the buttons in `CButtonColumn` to link to the appropriate actions for `OrderContents` model, while there are now linked to the actions of `Order` model. Is there any easy way to achieve this? I checked the API for both `CButtonColumn` and `CGridView` to see if I can get any inspiration there but had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't even need to create a custom button if all you want to do is change the urls. Look at `viewButtonUrl`, `updateButtonUrl` and  `deleteButtonUrl` for CButtonColumn.

You'd adjust the urls as shown the other answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example use of the `viewButtonUrl` attribute with CButtonColumn. I didn't find it straightforward figuring out how to provide the custom URL, but with a little wrangling I eventually got it. I thought I'd share it for others who might see this thread. Note that the PHP to generate the URL is passed as a *string*. Really?:

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
      'id'=>'artwork-grid',
      'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
      'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'artwork_id',
        'description',
        array(
          'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
          'viewButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(\'admin/artwork/\'. $data->id)',
          'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(\'admin/artwork/update/\'. $data->id)',
          'deleteButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(\'admin/artwork/delete/\'. $data->id)',
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this out there. I'd love to see!

Comment: +1 Cleaner solution by directly setting url inside viewButtonUrl, updateButtonUrl and deleteButtonUrl with CButtonColumn.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom button.

```
array(
       'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
       'buttons'=>array(
                        'myButton'=>array(
                             'label'=>'label of the button', //hover text
                             'imageUrl'=> 'link to an image',//icon of the button
                             'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("controller/action")', //target of the button
                        ),
       'template'=>'{myButton}' //and others
     ),
```

Complete parameter list can be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn/#buttons-detail).

Comment: any idea what should be the `url`? Should I use absolute URL? And where are the default icons for buttons are located?

Comment: `url` should be something like `Yii::app()->createUrl("controller/action")`. The default icons are loaded into the assets folder, but you can use any url for that, as long as it is absolute

Comment: Thanks. Will need to pass the id as well. Any idea how to get it? I mean `'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("controller/action&id=somehow_get_current_id")'`

Comment: You can do `Yii::app()->createUrl("controller/action", array("id"=>$data->id)` if your model has an `id` property. `$data` represents your model when CGridView is parsing.